# Match m1 = regxuid.Match(part);

Tags: c#, regex

Hi i need some help with this code

```
using InfinityScript;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace IpCheck
{
    public class IpCheck : BaseScript
    {
        public IpCheck()
        {
            base.PlayerConnected += new Action<Entity>((Entity player) =>
            {
                CONTROL(player);
            });
        }
        private void CONTROL(Entity player)
        {
            string lmt = "a";
            string[] lmtArrays = File.ReadAllLines(@"scripts\\\\Configs\\\\IpCheck.cfg");
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)lmtArrays.Length; i++)
            {
                string lmt1 = lmtArrays[i];
                if (lmt1.StartsWith("Admin"))
                {
                    char[] chrArray = new char[] { '=' };
                    lmt = lmt1.Split(chrArray)[1];
                    string[] parts = lmt.Split(',');
                    foreach (string part in parts)
                    {
                        string NAME = player.GetField<string>("name");
                        string IPP = player.IP.Address.ToString();
                        string GUID = player.GUID.ToString();
                        string XUID = player.Call<string>("getxuid");
                        var val = part;
                        Regex regxuid = new Regex(XUID, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                        Match m1 = regxuid.Match(part);
                        Regex regip = new Regex(IPP, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                        Match mip = regip.Match(part);
                        if (m1.Success && mip.Success)
                        {
                            Log.Write(InfinityScript.LogLevel.Info, NAME + " IP:" + IPP + " XUID:" + XUID + " GUID:" + GUID);
                            return;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I want to read a file and get my id and ip so if the id exists and ip does not match player will get a notification but when i use if (m1.Success && mip.Success) it's not working if i use it like if (m1.Success) or if (mip.Success) it works but i need both id and the ip
Thank you

```
scripts\\\\Configs\\\\IpCheck.cfg
Admin=1100001f4552aav,192.168.0.15
```

Comment: Use: `||` instead of `&&` based on the way you have defined your logic.

Comment: i need to check both in same time example if the player has that id but not the ip he will be kicked if i use || does not work hope you understand what am trying to do

Comment: Do you have debug values of the actual values being compared? Also, if || works, is it always the same regex that is a success? And one more side question: is the regex needed? it seems easier to use string.compare with ordinalignorecase. Strictly speaking by using the dot of the ipaddress in a regex pattern unescaped, it means any char. Shouldn't give problems, just mentioning ;)

Comment: if i use one of m1.Success or mip.Success it works if i use || m1.Success || mip.Success again it works but if i use it like m1.Success && mip.Success wont work and regex it's not needed if you can find a better solution feel free to share it thank you